# OnTouchEvent value of x of an event inside Horizontal Scroll View android

Tags: android

I want to ask that I have problem getting value of x of an event it moves but when it goes outside the screen then I move it further more it pulls me back. My target is to set width of linear layout as user move the the image in x direction and as it goes further increase or decrease accordingly. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.hk.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnTouchListener{
ImageView moveView;
LinearLayout leftLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    moveView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.moveView);
    moveView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    leftLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftLAyout);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        float x=event.getRawX();
        moveView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        leftLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)x, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return true;
    }
    else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        float x=event.getRawX();
        moveView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        Log.d("Value of x",""+x);
        leftLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)x, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

and my xml is

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/leftLAyout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hellow World"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hellow World"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftLAyout"
            android:id="@+id/moveView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/moveView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hellow World"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hellow World"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is log when i first move the image...

```
04-11 14:59:55.465  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 440.31216
04-11 14:59:55.503  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 465.3921
04-11 14:59:55.531  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 485.9376
04-11 14:59:55.563  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 504.9408
04-11 14:59:55.591  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 514.19507
04-11 14:59:55.652  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 549.30646
04-11 14:59:55.685  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 564.1517
04-11 14:59:55.714  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 580.76984
04-11 14:59:55.745  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 598.6162
04-11 14:59:55.771  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 607.72504
04-11 14:59:55.801  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 625.9001
04-11 14:59:55.832  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 644.7892
04-11 14:59:55.861  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 661.1286
04-11 14:59:55.892  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 676.2267
04-11 14:59:55.919  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 683.47046
04-11 14:59:55.947  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 697.8671
04-11 14:59:55.978  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 706.47736
04-11 14:59:56.009  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 710.5
```

Now it goes out of my screen then i scroll the screen horizontally i got this result...

```
04-11 14:59:55.919  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 683.47046
04-11 14:59:55.947  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 697.8671
04-11 14:59:55.978  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 706.47736
04-11 14:59:56.009  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 710.5
04-11 15:03:43.317  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 239.1455
04-11 15:03:43.346  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 253.11702
04-11 15:03:43.374  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 275.3185
04-11 15:03:43.407  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 298.59894
04-11 15:03:43.445  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 317.4518
04-11 15:03:43.475  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 336.22058
04-11 15:03:43.504  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 360.02032
04-11 15:03:43.537  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 385.87338
04-11 15:03:43.571  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 415.9991
04-11 15:03:43.602  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 451.37238
04-11 15:03:43.643  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 487.16537
04-11 15:03:43.676  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 539.1983
04-11 15:03:43.706  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 555.09204
04-11 15:03:43.733  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 583.9265
04-11 15:03:43.761  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 610.0864
04-11 15:03:43.790  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 623.09656
04-11 15:03:43.835  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 656.829
04-11 15:03:43.860  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 677.07996
04-11 15:03:43.887  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 687.8148
04-11 15:03:43.916  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 703.97144
04-11 15:03:43.943  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 710.79144
04-11 15:03:43.968  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 712.6507
04-11 15:03:43.992  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 716.4503
04-11 15:03:44.016  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 718.30524
04-11 15:03:44.041  24337-24337/com.example.hk.myapplication D/Value of x﹕ 719.5
```